# Running Typescript from Launchd

Tags: launchd

I would like to run a TypeScript script from a launchd.

I'm successfully running the script directly using `npx ts-node /path/to/script.ts`

However I can't figure out how to code this into the plist file. I have:

```
<key>ProgramArguments</key>
<array>
    <string>npx</string>
    <string>ts-node</string>
    <string>/path/to/script.ts</string>
</array>
```

But this exits with code 78. It would seem npx cannot be found (I see that in the LaunchControl app); but I can't figure out how to address npx correctly.

**Update**: Fixed the code 78 thanks to @nohillside and updated `npx` to `/usr/local/bin/npx`; but now logging the error `env: node: No such file or directory`

Comment: [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34215527/what-does-launchd-status-78-mean-why-my-user-agent-not-running) may give you some clues on further troubleshooting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely the path to `npx` is not in the default `PATH`. Run `type npx` in Terminal and then use the full path shown for the first string in your launchd plist.

As the PATH issue can proliferate, the actually better way might be to create a wrapper (shell) script which gets called by launchd, and export a adapted PATH in that script before calling npx.

Comment: Thank you; I didn't know about `type`; getting further - but now exits with 127 with the error `env: node: No such file or directory` logged

Comment: @BenRobinson This basically is the same issue again. I‘ve added a second option to the answer.

Comment: Your absolutely correct that PATH was the issue, however I was able to fix it by adding `<key>EnvironmentVariables</key><dict><key>PATH</key><string>/usr/local/bin:/bin</string></dict>` to the plist - thanks